# Enhanced Related List is not visible for custom profile

Tags: related-list, lightning-page, enhancedlist

I created two related custom objects. I have a related list in the Main Object where I need to see six fields.

I assign the type-related list as Enhanced List and with the Sysadmin, I can see the fields, but when I log in with the custom profile user, I can't see the fields.

what. I have done so far:

- App, Profile, and Page Layout assignments Checked
- visibility on all the fields Checked
- Permission on the custom objects Checked
- Validate on Customize Page Personal Settings but same result.

I don't know what else I can see. Any Thoughts?

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried this https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000388746&type=1

Comment: Yes, Already validated this and same result. It seems to be like the enhanced related list is set only for sysadmin, the page for standard users looks like the list was a basic one

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. I don't understand the cause, but my solution was to create a new page layout, with the same configuration. So I finally deleted the default one and it's working now.

Hope that it helps if anyone has the same problem.